# Meteor not displaying information from collection in html

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I am trying to get information from a collection in meteor and using a helper passing it to a template.

Here is my code on server.js:

```
Meteor.publish('dataForTableD1', function () {
    return Day1.find( { period: 1 } );
});
```

Here is my code on client.js:

```
Template.timetable.helpers({
    'day1p1': function() {
        Meteor.subscribe('dataForTableD1');
    }
});
```

Here is the template code:

```
{#with day1p1}}
    <td>{{lesson}}</td>
{{/with}}
```

The problem is that it won't display anything in the rendered page.

I am sure this is probably a typo or something similar on my part as I am quite new to meteor so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just subscribing to `dataForTableD1` but you don't return data in your `day1p1` helper function. You probably want to use [**`collection.findOne([selector], [options])`**](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/findone) to return a document that matches a selector.

Please try this:

```
Template.timetable.helpers({
    'day1p1': function() {
        Meteor.subscribe('dataForTableD1');
        return Day1.findOne(); // add here your selector and options
    }
});
```